# Can I run Ubuntu solely from an external drive?

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, external-hdd

I have an older laptop which has the GRUB menu setup and dual boots Ubtuntu 17.04/Windows 8.1.  I need to replace the hard drive in it because it's only a 5400 RPM.  The new drive will have Windows installed on it, however, I would still like to access Ubuntu from my old 2.5" drive using an external enclosure.  My laptop is already set to boot from USB.

Is it possible to run Ubuntu solely from this external drive that is setup as a dual boot even though the primary drive will now be only Windows 10?  Is there anything special I need to do, or will it detect GRUB at boot even though it's external?   I guess what I'm looking for is being able to plug this external into any Windows machine and just run Ubuntu from it and store all the files and changes on the external OS without affecting the machine it's plugged into.

Is this easy to do?  How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Just a bit of a linux newb, but here's what I discovered in setting up Ubuntu 18.04 on a thumbdrive so I can carry my own OS around with me everywhere.

1. If you do this, you need to be 100% certain never to prematurely unplug the drive before your computer is fully shut down, or you'll have no end of headaches.
2. It's possible to accidentally overwrite your main drive's bootloader, making the very act of booting your PC dependent on having your USB drive connected, windows installed on the non-portable hard drive or not. Best to be certain you're setting up correctly every step of the way.
3. Install grub MBR rather than EFI in order to achieve full compatibility in booting on older machines, though having it ALSO installed in an efi partition is handy if you want to attach it to something like a mac (which is a pain in the ass to switch compatible USB booting on for.)
4. (Optional) As a helpful note, I had a spare laptop lying around I could afford to mess up the OS install on, confident that in the worst case I'd just nuke-and-pave it. If you've got a spare lying around, set up your portable OS from that laptop instead and just move the drive over to your main device after the fact.

This guide was extremely useful to me in setting up my portable Ubuntu.

https://www.dionysopoulos.me/253-portable-ubuntu-on-usb-hdd.html

Answer (score 0):

I would get a sub 3.0 stick to hold the contents of what you need from the 5400 drive. This way you have the higher speed of 3.0, even if the computer only supports 2.0 it will still run fast. I'm afraid the old drive is likely to fail especially in a portable setting.